# how to close colorbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

hi i have a link when clicked opens a colorbox with a form in it what i want that when i click on the submit button the form will be submitted via ajax and based on the returned data

```
 if(error on the server side){
   the error will be displayed at the top of the form;
   // colorbox still open
 }else{
   the returned data will be displayed on the original page;
   close the colorbox;
 }
```

so i did all that except the close colorbox part i used this code:

```
$.colorbox.close();
```

and this didn't work too:

```
parent.jQuery.colorbox.close();
```

any help, thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had this a while back, cant remember which it is...

Try this...

```
$(window).colorbox.close();
```

or this...

```
jQuery(window).colorbox.close();
```

or this...

```
jQuery('#cboxClose').click();
```